# iOS: App crash because of [OS_dispatch_data notifyDelegateOnWillFinish]?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, crash

On some devices my app is crashing because of the following error:
NSInvalidArgumentException: -[OS_dispatch_data notifyDelegateOnWillFinish]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2082d7a0

I am not able to reproduce this behavior. I track crashes with flurry analytics and some users seems to experience this problem.

I tried to google this error with no success. So hopefully somebody here knows what that means.

Thanks a lot!!

EDIT:
The only part in my code where I use dispatch is this

```
- (void) callDelegateOnMainThread: (SEL) selector withArg: (id) arg error: (NSError*) err
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
               {
                   [self callDelegate: selector withArg: arg error: err];
               });
}
```

EDIT2:
And here is the callDelegate method:

```
- (void) callDelegate: (SEL) selector withArg: (id) arg error: (NSError*) err
{
    assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
    if([delegate respondsToSelector: selector])
    {
        if(arg != NULL)
        {
            [delegate performSelector: selector withObject: arg withObject: err];
        }
        else
        {
            [delegate performSelector: selector withObject: err];
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        DebugLog(@"Missed Method");
    }
}
```

Is there a problem with this code? Please advise! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sounds like something got prematurely deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not implemented notifyDelegateOnWillFinish method in your class.

You should add check before calling delegate methods like.

```
if([delegate respondsToSelector:selector])
    [self callDelegate: selector withArg: arg error: err];
```